# Polynomial and closed path

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, holomorphic-functions

I need help with this task.
I have to prove that $$\int_{\gamma} P(z)dz =0$$ for every polynomial $P$ and every closed path $\gamma$ in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You know that if you have a primitive then....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: You should state what proof means you are allowed to use. Because by the Cauchy Integral Theorem this is obvious.

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti Do you assume $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth or anything?

Comment: @YvesDaoustv Do you assume $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth or anything?

Comment: @BCLC just assuming that $\gamma$ is closed

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti from closed but NOT piecewise smooth, how do you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

IF $\gamma$ IS PIECEWISE SMOOTH:

$\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}a_{n}z^{n+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2}a_{1}z^{2}+a_{0}z\right)'=a_{n}z^{n}+\cdots+a_{1}z+a_{0}:=P(z)$, so the integral is just the difference of the endpoints of $y$ taken by the primitive.

Comment: Do you assume $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth or anything?

Answer (score 0):

IF $\gamma$ IS PIECEWISE SMOOTH:

Then since $\gamma$ is closed, and polynomials are entire and have primitives (which are also polynomials), we can conclude from either

1. Cauchy's Integral Theorem
2. The complex analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

OTHERWISE:

Then I can understand why you would need help.